# Where would consciousness be located in a machine?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness, artificial-intelligence

The conscious thought I experience is behind my eyes and is located within my skull. I assume that experience is common. however, it may not be?

In replicating consciousness in a machine such as a computer, where will its conscious experience be located?

In the ram, the processor, for example?

Comment: Consciousness does not have physical attributes, like position, size, volume or shape. In addition, the definition is subjective when it comes to its emergence in non-human entities: in any case, rocks can be conscious, depending on the definition.

Comment: @RodolfoAP I can not say where my subconscious and motor function is located. However, my conscious thought is behind my eyes and remains there wherever my body goes. Wherever the hell my body  is located, I agree, is questionable?

Comment: but thanks for the insights! i can hardly locate my "conscious thought", but i can "focus anywhere" (i can imagine)   ..in chinese philosophy/language "they have" two souls! one spiritual and one physical...but which is which!? ;p

Comment: It would be in the pineal gland, same as in humans. /s

Comment: Most people point to their chest when they express a very strong sense of something — *I say with all my heart that...* They may *say* heart but usually it's center-sternum or even to the right. So it's heartish but not quite the physical heart. Probably solar plexus. There's also *gut feeling*, *soul peering out of the eyes* And even *vote with feet*. So I question whether your sense of consciousness location has verisimilitude

Comment: The consciousness will be created by the software and hardware in tandem.

Comment: @8Mad0Manc8 "Wherever the hell my body is located, I agree, is questionable": yes, it is absolutely questionable, due to its pure nature of _subjectivity_, while philosophy and science target the opposite, _objectivity_.

Comment: >The consciousness will be created by the software and hardware in tandem. On that day, @IdiosyncraticSoul, I will transfer you `4509840913987983298239852908234$`!

Comment: Sorry guys, "consciousness" is "truth" is "ideal" it has (like "all ideal") NO location (for what?/where should that be?) ... Matter/sh#t on the other hand (ever) has location. No one can "locate truth". "Everyone" can locate "sh#t"!

Comment: the only "logic" answer to the location of "any idea" is "everywhere"(and "nowhere") is "never" (and ever) ..it before/after and between each (time/space) "point"...

Comment: I don't get the votes to close this question for being a matter of opinion. Just because you have no answer doesn't mean the answer is a matter of opinion. Although the question is flawed, it is touching on some very significant metaphysical issues.

Comment: @Rushi My conscious experience is behind my mind that is what is real for me and it has a location I hear the sequence of thought of my words I have felt guilt and that is located in the stomach and that is not a mental experience it's a physical one, as a consequence of a mental action.

Comment: Although it doesn’t answer the question, you might be interested in Daniel Dennett’s "Where am I ?" short story (it’s only 8 pages and there’s a free PDF online), a thought experiment on dissociation of body and brain.  It might serves as feed for thought.

Comment: In its structure? That is, intelligence, consciousness, etc. are properties emergent from complex structures (be that neural nets, or some digital data structures).

Answer (score 3):

1. The question where to locate consciousness is asked in current
   neuroscience in the form:

   > What are the neural correlates of consciousness (NCC)?

   Consciousness is not a **substance** somewhere located in the brain.
   It is a property of certain mental **processes** in the cortex.

   The model of computation in the brain does not follow the
   original computer model with a CPU and a separate memory for sequential
   processing.

   The basic model is the neuronal net with distributed
   parallel processing, see [Neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network).
2. You find many references to NCC in the internet when searching for
   Christof Koch. In particular his book [Consciousness](https://www.amazon.de/Consciousness-MIT-Press-Christof-Koch/dp/0262017490).
3. More advanced is his paper with several coauthors
   [Neural correlates of consciousness: progress and problems](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjmosaQ_b-DAxWthv0HHRyIABwQFnoECBcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nature.com%2Farticles%2Fnrn.2016.22&usg=AOvVaw2EWcm3eTOWKKOmjMyobv3_&opi=89978449) from 2016. The
   abstract of this paper says:

   > There have been a number of advances in the search for the neural
   > correlates of consciousness — the minimum neural mechanisms sufficient
   > for any one specific conscious percept. In this Review, we describe
   > recent findings showing that the anatomical neural correlates of
   > consciousness are primarily localized to a posterior cortical hot zone
   > that includes sensory areas, rather than to a fronto-parietal network
   > involved in task monitoring and reporting. We also discuss some
   > candidate neurophysiological markers of consciousness that have proved
   > illusory, and measures of differentiation and integration of neural
   > activity that offer more promising quantitative indices of
   > consciousness.

   Apparently, progress in understanding conscious human processes is the prerequisite for any simulation of consciousness in machines.
4. **Added** due to comment: The most simple type of a conscious perception is a quale, e.g., a colour perception. A quale is
   experienced from the first person viewpoint (subjective). The
   creation of a quale must be explained on the third person level
   (objective). It is important not to mix up the two levels of
   perception resp. explanation.

Comment: I think this claim "Consciousness is not a substance somewhere located in the brain. It is a property of certain mental processes in the cortex." Isn't correct, as much as people insist on it. Why? Well take examples of process and substance. Like movement. In this case, it's very clear that there is an object that moves. *But how is it so clear that my experience is electric charges that move in a pattern ?* (modelled as Neural Nets).

Comment: Sure, but the problem is why there is the 1st person experience (also, a person could study its own brain and try to explain how does it produce that experience literally, not in correlation terms), the 3rd person is less interesting. I purposely used 'my' for that reason.

Comment: Colour is just quantized energy and doesn't exist in the object world. it only exists in the subject that experiences that object. Energy does not have a colour. Well, that's my take on qualia?

Answer (score 1):

To be precise, there are two questions to be asked: where does the neural correlate happen, and where does a consciousness locate itself.

The first question is technical, and the  answer is simply that all devices required to perform the calculations can be considered as location, and there are many devices and variations possible. As an example the calculations could be distributed across many computers around the world.

The second question is flawed, it assumes both that an artificial consciousness needs to be humanlike and locate itself, and that all artificial consciousnesses would be same.

Currently, neither assumption is required and they both seem premature. Any two artificial consciousnesses might be very different from each other, the same way any two smartphone apps can be different from each other. We can imagine artificial consciousnesses without any sense of self location, we can imagine some with biologically inspired feeling of embodiment, we can imagine some with a feeling of being located in multiple places at once. All of those variants could exist in the future in different devices.

But for a life-inspired design, it would probably make more sense for a consciousness to have a body (even if simulated) and then locate itself around it's main sensors (camera eyes, microphone ears), rather than the location of information processing.

Comment: I experience my conscous thought in my head. My conscious thought is a linear sequence of words which I 'hear' similar to sound, in my mind. I would claim that is the conscious self and I am aware it is behind my eyes. I would argue if the AI could not tell you where its concious self is located it is not self aware.?

Comment: Having an internal voice as a point of reference can be psychologically enough to be self aware, if you will. But generally there is no reason to expect that we can imagine how it feels to be such an AI.

Answer (score 0):

> The conscious thought I experience is behind my eyes and is located within my skull. I assume that experience is common. however, it may not be?

It should be noted, I think, that you would feel like this *even if it weren't true*.

Like, imagine this: imagine you have you brain in a computer lab, and 5 meters away from your brain, your brains nervous system is hooked up to the eyes and body of your body, which your brain has been cut out of. Imagine somehow that scientists managed to entirely relocate your brain, but keep all the connections in-tact, so your brain is still receiving all the sensory information it would have normally received if it were still in your skull, but now it's not in your skull.

Where would you feel like your consciousness is in that case? Would you feel like it's where your brain is, or would you feel like it's "behind your eyes"?

I would bet it would feel like it's behind your eyes.

So what does this say about computer consciousness, and "where" computer consciousness would be? Well, I think it first of all depends very much on if we give this computer consciousness a live sensory input similar to our own eyes and ears and smell - if it doesn't have that, the "where" question might not even be meaningful to begin with.

Comment: I would argue that you could still ask the AI where its conscous resides and if it could not give you an answer then either it's self aware and self-awareness does not need to have a location of the self, or it's not self aware?

Comment: Well... yes, but you've just kind of laid out all the options there. Either A is the case, or not-A is the case. @8Mad0Manc8

Comment: @8Mad0Manc8 I feel like I could imagine having conscious experience *without* having any sensory input, can you? If so... wouldn't that be exactly what it feels like to not have a strong sense of location of self?

Comment: Yes we have a conscious experience when we dream and that information I guess you could argue does not come from the senses, and if you are lucid dreaming then you have an experience of the self, being self aware of yourself and of the dream you are experiencing.